# Labview - Managing large numbers of constants

Tags: constants, labview

This is more of a formatting problem than code logic and probably seems silly (considering I've seen far more dense block diagrams). I'm working with a lot of numeric constants and they're starting to clutter my Block Diagram. Is there something I can use to group them nice and compactly?

Preferably I would like to avoid clustering them because I would need to bundle and unbundle every time I needed access.

EDIT: Picture of code in question (code segment is used repeatedly, so would be nice to have a more compact case structure)

[image]

Comment: Constants usually aren't an issue for me (variables yes, but constants, no). Would you post some code so we can see your issue firsthand?

Comment: I ended up just moving some functions around and making more space for the constants. I have posted a picture of a portion of the code. It doesn't look bad now, but I suppose my question is still relevant because the portion of code I shared is actually repeated quite a lot for different case structures, and so having a more compact way to display the constants would be nice

Comment: If it's something you're going to use over and over, make it into a subvi. http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7593/en/

Comment: Although that would work, I'd like to be able to see each of the case structures executing without having to click into separate subvi diagrams (at least for now while I'm still debugging). Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rethink how much of your block diagram you expect to devote to constants :-)

Using numbers directly in code, the equivalent of unlabelled constants on the LabVIEW block diagram, is a recognised [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). Unless the reason for the constant value is both obvious and fundamental to the operation being carried out, anyone looking at your code (including you, any time after a couple of weeks since you wrote it) will not understand why the value was chosen. Therefore, you should make this clear by labelling the constant somehow (equivalent to assigning it to a name in a text language) and also make it easy to change the value if necessary.

It's usually clear what a `0` or `1` constant is doing there but in the code image you've posted you have two constants of `1000` and one of `999`. Why is it 1000, and if I decide that it should be (say) 2000 instead, do I need to update the other two values as well? If so you should define it once, label it with a suitable name describing what it is (in your example it might be `chunk size` or something) and wire that value to wherever you need to use it. Where you have a constant `999` you could get that value with a Decrement function, or you could also change your `Greater Than` function to a `Greater or Equal` and compare directly with the 1000 value. In this way your initial constant definition will take up more space because of the label, but you'll save space and improve maintainability by wiring that value to wherever you need it rather than placing additional constants.

If you need to refer to the same constants in multiple places on your block diagram, you can place the constants (and just the constants, not any other program logic) in a subVI, with each constant wired to an indicator with a suitable label, and each indicator wired to a different output on the connector pane. When you hover the wiring tool over the SubVI's terminals you'll see the label in the tip-strip. Alternatively, especially if you need loads of different constant values, you can do the same thing but in your SubVI bundle the different constants into a named cluster (which you save as a typedef), and then use `Unbundle by Name` to access specific constant values from the cluster where you need them. Again this doesn't necessarily save block diagram space, but it does make your code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I've been coding for several years in Python, but have recently started working with LabVIEW, so any and all advice even with regard to documenting code is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer was to reorganize my block diagram making more space for the constants. Dave_St suggested creating subvi's for the case structures for anyone looking for alternatives. Wanted to mark this as resolved regardless.